# Choosing low-pass filter parameters

Tags: matlab, filter

I have position of objects from recording sampled at 30 fps. I wish to remove high frequencies from position with the help of low-pass filter.

I am confused as to how to choose the filter parameters in this respect->

```
[b,a] = butter(n,Wn)
```

that is , `n` and `Wn` in this case.

Data:

```
K>> [xcor_i,ycor_i ]

ans =

 -101.7000  -77.4040
 -102.4200  -77.4040
 -103.6600  -77.4040
 -103.9300  -76.6720
 -103.9900  -76.5130
 -104.0000  -76.4780
 -105.0800  -76.4710
 -106.0400  -77.5660
 -106.2500  -77.8050
 -106.2900  -77.8570
 -106.3000  -77.8680
 -106.3000  -77.8710
 -107.7500  -78.9680
 -108.0600  -79.2070
 -108.1200  -79.2590
 -109.9500  -80.3680
 -111.4200  -80.6090
 -112.8200  -81.7590
 -113.8500  -82.3750
 -115.1500  -83.2410
 -116.1500  -83.4290
 -116.3700  -83.8360
 -117.5000  -84.2910
 -117.7400  -84.3890
 -118.8800  -84.7770
 -119.8400  -85.2270
 -121.1400  -85.3250
 -123.2200  -84.9800
 -125.4700  -85.2710
 -127.0400  -85.7000
 -128.8200  -85.7930
 -130.6500  -85.8130
 -132.4900  -85.8180
 -134.3300  -86.5500
 -136.1700  -87.0760
 -137.6500  -86.0920
 -138.6900  -86.9760
 -140.3600  -87.9000
 -142.1600  -88.4660
 -144.7200  -89.3210
```

Code:

```
[b,a] = butter(6,0.6,'low');
dataOut_x = filter(b,a,xcor_i);
dataOut_y = filter(b,a,ycor_i);

K>> plot(xcor_i,ycor_i,'Linewidth',2 );
K>> hold on
K>> plot(dataOut_x,dataOut_y,'Linewidth',2)
```

[image]

Clearly, my parameters aren't correct.

Comment: Think simpler.  Have you tried a more simpler low-pass filter? What about a simple local averaging?  What exactly are you trying to filter? Give us more background.

Comment: If you are sampling at 30fps, the cut-off frequency of your filter, as coded, is 0.6*15 = 9 fps, meaning you should be filtering stuff above that frequency. is that what you want?

Comment: @rayryeng I have tried a simple moving average, doesn't work that well. I am recording people from an overheard camera. I have tracks of each's head using some software. I want to periodicity from tracks due to head wobbling.

Comment: @am304 filtering above that frequency retaining only lower frequency. But parameters selection is rather tricky for me.

Comment: I wouldn't consider that as "high" frequency at all.... I would consider that to be an outlier due to human freedom of movement.  I would probably rethink your approach with high frequency and try something else.  Perhaps something like interpolation.  In another viewpoint, what do you *expect* to see when you filter your results?  That you haven't made clear.

Comment: @rayryeng Expectation: The guy being tracked is moving towards a point. The track should have major changes in motion removing any changes due to head wobbling.

Comment: I think interpolation is better for you.  Grab local windows of points and infer a smooth function then interpolate the motion between the end points of the windows.... or, if your points are small enough, use the entire dataset and fit a polynomial of sorts through those points.  Additional bonus for robustness if you throw in RANSAC.  I don't believe a low-pass filter is applicable here... I'd love to be proven wrong though.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia I think you should move this over to Signal Processing Stack Exchange: http://dsp.stackexchange.com.  This (to me) isn't a matter of what parameters you should choose but how you should approach this problem.  Consider moving over to that site and asking those users for insight.

Comment: @rayryeng http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28095/choosing-low-pass-filter-parameters

Comment: @rayryeng Consider I have sampling rate of 30fps and human can change direction every 0.5 secs. What could be the cut-off frequency and order?